# What is the faster way to draw colored string with XFT library?

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering, xlib, xorg

I have a string and an array that contains every character of the string format: color and font. Now I am using XFT library to draw this string char-by-char, using respective color and font (XftDrawStringUtf8 function). But this approach is slow.

I though about scanning the string and drawing the chunks with the same format at once. But this approach in some circumstances (if every character has different format) can be even slower than char-by-char approach.

Also, I read somewhere that drawing the string char by char is not good approach from the typographical point of view. Something about kerning.

Is there a faster and better way, using XFT library? Or using another library?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Render extension with CreateGlyphSet / CompositeGlyphs requests.

GlyphSet is array of rectangular pixmaps with offsets. Using CompositeGlyphs request you can render in one request ( one network packet one way ) quite a lot: It takes array of "glyphset elements", which is "array of char ids" + offset from end of last char in "array of ids" OR id of another glyphset to use. You can adjust kerning pairs by splitting input string into substrings at the point where kerning is non-zero. Colors are a bit trickier, one way would be to use source picture ( RenderCompositeGlyphs uses rendered text as a mask ) pre-colored with rectangles of the color you need.

In practice, especially if you need to support complex scripts (like Arabic) I'd suggest to render everything on client side pixmap with some high level library ( Pango / Cairo ) and transfer resulting picture to your drawable

If you just exploring possible limits another approach in addition to Render extension is to try to render everything using GPU with vertex and fragment shaders ( take a look at [glyphy](https://code.google.com/p/glyphy/) project. Also good source of information about text rendering in general on [Behdad Esfahbod](http://behdad.org/) page )

Comment: Do you mean using xrender library, or direct communication with the XServer?

Comment: XRender extension - whatever client you want ( xrender, xcb-render, python-xib-render, node-x11 etc )